# Where does function gets values

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp

There is a code:

```
(define (factorial a)
  (define (iter  b c)
    (if (> b a) c
        (iter (* b c)
              (+ b 1))
  (iter 1 1)
```

I got some questions:

1. The function stops when `b` become larger than `a` after n times of iterations?
2. If so, function must take the value `c` (because of `if (> b a) c)`, and to me it's seems like there is really no manipulation with `c` inside the code so it's just must display argument that we give at start? Or the values `(* b c)` goes to `c` (it really does), but why?

Comment: I think you have the arguments backwards in the recursion. It should be `(iter (+ b 1) (* b c))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be:

```
(define (factorial a)
  (define (iter  b c)
    (if (> b a) c
        (iter (+ b 1)
              (* b c))
  (iter 1 1))
```

with the arguments to `iter` in the other order.

1. Yes. Each recursion call with `b` incrementing by 1, so it will stop after `a` iterations.
2. When you call

```
(iter (+ b 1) (* b c))
```

`(* b c)` goes to `c` in the recursive call. So each recursion multiplies `c` by the current value of `b`. Since we add 1 to `b` each time, this results in multiplying `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 ...`, which is the definition of factorial.

Comment: It works for general case?It's always when we get function with n arguments, value goes to last argument

Comment: You can put arguments in any order you want. The value doesn't have to be last.